# Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet while removing empty rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gspread

I'm trying to print a bunch of data imported from Google Sheets using pandas and gspread without having lots of NaN values.
I noticed there's an option to skip over blank lines rather than interpreting as NaN values but it seems not working in my case.

Is there a way to skip all `NaN` values printing only the actual cells containing data?

This is the code

```
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gsframe

sheet = gc.open_by_key('sheet_id').worksheet('tab_name')
existing = gsframe.get_as_dataframe(sheet,skip_blank_lines=True)

print(existing)
```

And this is the output

```
0                        ID       Name  ...         NaN         
1                       NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2                       NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
3    ZZZ2021111100000711441          A  ...         NaN         NaN
4    ZZZ2021111100000711442          B  ...         NaN         NaN
5                       NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
..                      ...        ...  ...         ...         ...
992                     NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
993                     NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
994                     NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
995                     NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
996                     NaN        NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: First, try to use `skiprows=1` and `usecols=[0, 1]`. Does it work better?

Comment: The problem now is your first row should be your column names. Did you try to pass my parameters to `get_as_dataframe`?

Comment: Found the solution by dropping columns and rows separately by tweaking 
`existing = gsframe.get_as_dataframe(sheet).dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all').dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Can you try: `existing = gsframe.get_as_dataframe(sheet, skiprows=1, usecols=[0, 1]).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`